# Using for loop defined variable to print numbers (ERROR) (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to check if a number is prime or not. For that I am using 'for loop' with 'range' function. It turns out that one cannot use variables which iterate over range to print using 'format()' attribute of Python.

The basic problem with my code is given in the simplified code below.

```py
for num in range[1,4,1]:
    print("{} is a number").format(num)
```

I expected output to be

```py
1 is a number 
2 is a number
3 is a number
```

But the output is

```py
$python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    for num in range[1,4,1]:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: `range(1,4,1)` you need to use `()` to call a function

Comment: range is a function so you need to call it with parentheses like that: **range(1, 4, 1)** and print function won't work neither, it should be like that: **print("{} is a number".format(num))**

Answer (score 0):

Range does not work like that, 
you need to use parenthesis instead of square brackets :

```
for num in range(1,4,1) :
    print("{} is a number".format(num))
```

Comment: I do not want my output to be 
```python
1 is a number
4 is a number
1 is a number
```
 but 
```python
1 is a number
2 is a number
3 is a number
```
Here 1 is the lower limit, 4 is the upper limit and 1 is the step value of range function.

Comment: you have to use parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

> **The range()** function returns a sequence of numbers, starting from 0 by default, and increments by 1 (by default), and ends at a
>   specified number.
>
> *Syntax:*
>
> range(start, stop, step)+

You need to use `()` instead `[]` in this line:

```
for num in range[1,4,1]:
```

correct way is:

```
for num in range(1,4,1):
```

NOTE:

this is equal to:

```
for num in range(1,4):
```

step is optional and by Default is 1.

another mistake, you forgot the parenthesis at the end:

```
print("{} is a number".format(num))
```

code:

```
for num in range(1,4):
    print (("{} is a number").format(num))
```

output:

```
1 is a number
2 is a number
3 is a number
```